# Undefined symbol with GCC 7.2.0 and -O3

Tags: python, c++, gcc, cmake

We have a fairly large framework, which incompasses several `CMakeLists.txt` files and consists of several shared libraries. In the end we use SWIG to generate a Cython interface.

Everything works on MacOS, that is we can compile with `cmake` and `make install` and use our framework from within python with `import x`. Everything also works just fine on Ubuntu using GCC-6.

However, when using GCC 7.2.0 (with Ubuntu 17.10) with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` we get the following error:

```
ImportError: /home/madsohm/.local/lib/libbhc.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSaIlEC1Ev
```

when trying to `import`. Using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` works fine, so it must be the `-O3` added by `Release` that is the culprit.

I have tried to search the `so`-files for the symbol, and got

```
$ scanelf -l -s _ZNSaIlEC1Ev | grep _ZNSaIlEC1Ev
ET_DYN _ZNSaIlEC1Ev /usr/lib/libbhxx.so
ET_DYN _ZNSaIlEC1Ev /usr/lib/libbhc.so
ET_DYN _ZNSaIlEC1Ev /usr/lib/libbh.so
```

when having `Debug` but only

```
$ scanelf -l -s _ZNSaIlEC1Ev | grep _ZNSaIlEC1Ev
ET_DYN _ZNSaIlEC1Ev /usr/lib/libbhc.so
```

with `Release`.

`_ZNSaIlEC1Ev` demangled is `std::allocator<long>::allocator()`.

Is there anyway I can figure out what the symbol is referring to or where the fault is and what I can do about it?

Comment: Smells like some ODR violation, i.e. a bug in your C++ code.